# Is there anyway to get around this compiler optimization in C?

Tags: c, bit, compiler-optimization, bit-shift

I want to note that, as pointed out by Olaf, the compiler is not at fault.

---

*Disclaimer: I'm not entirely sure this behavior is due to compiler optimization.*

Anyways, in C I'm trying to determine whether the n-th bit (n should be  between 0 and 7, inclusive) of an 8-bit byte is `1` or `0`. I initially came up with this solution:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool one_or_zero( uint8_t t, uint8_t n ) // t is some byte, n signifies which bit
{
    return (t << (n - (n % 8) - 1)) >> 7;
}
```

Which, from my previous understanding, would do the following to a byte:

Suppose `t = 5` and `n = 2`. Then the byte `t` can be represented as `0000 0101`. I assumed that `(t << (n - (n % 8) - 1))` would shift the bits of `t` so that `t` is `1010 0000`. This assumption is only somewhat correct. I also assumed the next bit shift (`>> 7`) would shift the bits of `t` so that `t` is `0000 0001`. This assumption is also only somewhat correct.

**TL;DR**: I thought the line `return (t << (n - (n % 8) - 1)) >> 7;` did this:

1. `t` is `0000 0101`
2. The first bit shift occurs; `t` is now `1010 0000`
3. The second bit shift occurs; `t` is now `0000 0001`
4. `t` is returned as `0000 0001`

Although I intend for that to happen, it does not. Instead, I have to write the following, to get my intended results:

```
bool one_or_zero( uint8_t t, uint8_t n ) // t is some byte, n signifies which bit
{
    uint8_t val = (t << (n - (n % 8) - 1));
    return val >> 7;
}
```

I know that adding `uint8_t val` isn't a massive performance drain. Still, I'd like to know two things:

1. **Do I have to initialize another variable to do what I intend?**
2. **Why doesn't the one-liner do the same thing as the two-liner?**

I'm under the impression that when the compiler optimizes my code, it smashes the two bit shifts together so only one occurs. This seems like a nice thing, but it doesn't "clear" the other bits as intended.

Comment: General hint: You should not assume **the compiler** is wrong until you prove you are **not**.

Comment: looks like you have to be careful of type casting on the return

Comment: What did you think `(n-(n%8)-1)` would result in?

Comment: @DavidHammen Shift the n-th bit all the way to the left, essentially "clearing" the bits to the left of the n-th one.

Comment: "Shift the n-th bit all the way to the left" -- that wasn't David's question. What *value* do you think `(n-(n%8)-1)` has? The shift doesn't happen until the value of the expression is calculated. You wrote an expression and you've made several claims as to what shifting by that amount will do, but it's obvious that it won't if you bother to think about how much (n-(n%8)-1)` is ... which you have nowhere calculated.

Comment: !!(t & (1 << n)) would be a better solution to check if nth bit is set or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That code is very complicated just to check a bit in an integer. Try the standard method:

```
return (t & (1U << n)) != 0;
```

If you have to check n is valid, add an assertion. else masking `(n & 7)` or modulus `(n % 8)` (this will be optimized by the compiler to the mask-operation) will force the shift count in a valid range. As that pattern will be recognized by many compilers, they might transform this to a single bit-test CPU instruction if available.

To avoid magic numbers, you should replace the modulus `8` by: `(sizeof(t) * CHAR_BIT)`. That will follow any type `t` might have. The mask is always one less than the modulus.

Your code:

```
(n - (n % 8) - 1))
```

If `n < 8` it yields a negative value (`-1` precisely). [Negative shifts](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p3) present [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so anything can happen (watch out for nasal demons).

Comment: The negative shift is good to point out, but I don't think it can happen in my code because `n` is unsigned.

Comment: @gragas: If you refer to right shifts in general: Read about _integer promotion_! `unit8_t` will be first promoted to `int` for the operation! However, _negative_ shifts, as well as shifts with the same or larger bit-size than the left operand **are** _undefined_ independent of signed-ness! Read the links I included.

Comment: @gragas - Suppose both the 8 and 1 are expressed as `uint8_t` values and `n` is between 0 and 7 (inclusive). With this, `(n-(n%uint8_t(8))-uint8_t(1))` is 255. Shifting left by 255 bits is undefined behavior.

Comment: @DavidHammen: `n` is promoted to `int` before the shift, so the expression is `int`.

Comment: `n - (n % 8) -  1` is simply the wrong value ... it should be `7 - n`.

Comment: @JimBalter: Why that? That would reverse the bit-order.  Very likely OP wanted to force the shift-count into a valid range by the modulus.

Comment: @JimBalter 0 to 7 is 8.

Comment: The OP wants n = 2 to shift left by 5, so that the nth bit is the high bit of the byte ... then he shifts right by 7 to put it in the low bit. It's a roundabout way to do it, but in any case `n - (n % 8) - 1 ` is completely wrong ... it has the same value for 0-7, 8-15, etc.

Comment: Actually so. "Take n = 8: 8 - 0 - 1 = 7" ... yes, and the expression is also 7 for n = 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, and 15. " For n < 8, it always yields -1" -- *as I said*, it has the same value. That's obviously not what is wanted, since he's trying to isolate a specific bit. Now I'm done talking to you again.

Comment: @JimBalter: Calm down, I just have missinterpreted you. Sorry for that! (You really should show more tolerance if someone does not instantly get what you mean)

Comment: You're the one using exclamation marks and being rude (as usual). Goodbye.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are the victim of integer promotion.

When you have an expression: `x operator y` there are a few things you should be aware of. The first is that the result (and in the process the other operand) of the expression is promoted to the "largest" type of the two operands.

In your example, this means the following:

1. `(t << (n - (n % 8) - 1)) >> 7;` The constant 8 is an `int` therefore `n%8` is also an `int`.
2. `(t << (n - (integer) - 1)) >> 7`  `(n - integer - 1)` is also an integer, which means that the temporary value `(t << integer)` will be stored in an `int`. This means that you don't "cut off" the most significant bits like you intend, because the result is stored in (most likely) 32 bits, and not 8 like you presume.

If you on the other hand temporarily store the `int` result in an `uint8_t` you will correctly cut off the leading bits and get what you intend.

The you can work around the problem by casting your operands to uint8_t during the computation:

```
(t << (uint8_t)(n - (n % 8) - 1))) >> 7;
```

Or even better, use a mask like suggested in the answer by Olaf:

```
(t & ((uint8_t)1 << n)) != 0
```

Comment: The result of the cast will then be converted to `int` for the shift operator, still negative. Even **if** if would not, it's size will be larger than the bitsize of the left operand, still presenting UB!

Comment: @Olaf Well the result of the << expression would be uint8 and the result of the >> expression would be int. Which is fine since dropping bits on the right hand side would behave the same for both types.

Comment: `t << (uint8_t)(n - (n % 8) - 1))`. Both sides are first [promoted](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1p1) to `int`. The right side yields `255` (I was wrong about `-1` actually). As that is larger than the bitsize of an `int` (even if not promoted), it is UB. No need to care about the right shift anymore!

Comment: I believe the right shift is there to ensure that the final answer is in the range [0,1] so I stand by that my code is still correct. Your suggestion is still a better way to do it as we all agree.